# Displacement applied before stretching

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm in blender render, I have a material and I rendered a material with clouds. I want these clouds to be stretched horizontally so they make ovaloid globules instead of spherical ones.

The diffuse color and normal both render this properly, giving me stretched clouds. When I use displacement however, it acts as though the material was not horizontally stretched and so gives me spherical globules instead of ovaloid ones. How can I change this applied order?

Comment: FYI No one is using blender-render anymore... good luck

Comment: I don't use it for commercial projects either, I use it for quicker previews, so it seems like you're just trolling.

Comment: *Eevee* (its replacement as of 2.8) is even faster in most cases.

Comment: That has not been the case in my experience.